# Nodemon - exclusion of files

Tags: nodemon

I would like to exclude some specific files from monitoring of NodeMon. How can I do this?

My existing configuration:

```
nodemon: {
      all: {
        script: 'app.js',
        options: {
          watchedExtensions: ['js']
        }
      }
```

Comment: I presume I should edit the `.nodemon-ignore` file in the root of the application...

Answer (score 288, accepted):

In order to make NodeMon ignore a bunch of files from monitoring, you can start it as

```
nodemon --ignore PATTERN [--ignore PATTERN2]
```

where PATTERN is the name of a specific file, directory, or wildcard pattern. Make sure that if you use a wildcard, it is escaped.

For example

```
nodemon --ignore 'lib/*.js' --ignore README
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to configure that behaviour instead, try creating a `nodemon.json` file in your current working directory, or your home directory. You can configure ignoring some files by adding something like the following to this config file:

```
{   
    "ignore": ["lib/*.js", "README"] 
}
```

Refer the README file at https://github.com/remy/nodemon for more details.

Comment: didnt' work for me, I needed to use path without simple-quotes: `nodemon --ignore public/ build.js`
This is maybe due to french keyboard layout in windows...

Comment: not work for me to. but i  use npx or npm script.mybbe that the reason,

Comment: On Windows quoting with single quotes does not work. Double quotes do work.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer, seemed to work fine with single quotes on powershell, at least for the first variant.

Comment: This works for me in my package.json so it only restarts if I make changes to my server. `"scripts": {  "start": "nodemon --ignore public/*"  }`

Answer (score 62):

You can add nodemon configuration within package.json file
For example:

```
{
  "name": "nlabel",
  "version": "0.0.1",
   // other regular stuff


  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": ["public/data/*.json", "public/javascripts/*.js"]
  },


  "author": "@sziraqui",
  "license": "GPL-3.0"
}
```

The key must be "nodemonConfig". Ignore rules can be specified as array of globs or complete filenames

More info: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#packagejson

Comment: Couldn't get any version of `--ignore` to work but this did. Clean solution as well.

Comment: Can I get info on terminal which files/folders are excluded in `nodemon`? I just see Nico's answer, should help

Comment: @Timo Couldn't find any nodemon config for your use case. You can use `ls 'your exlusions' && nodemon app.js` (not cross platform). If you are willing to write code for it, you can listen to nodemon 'start' or 'restart' event and print excluded files by reading nodemon config and expanding glob patterns in "ignore" array.

Answer (score 13):

For me (Mac and nodemon 1.18.3), the only way to ignore entire directories is to run e.g.

```
nodemon --ignore "**/old/**"
```

with the double quote and **. The config file won't work.

I have set up an alias like this:

```
alias nm='nodemon server.js -i "**/old/**" -i "**/img/**"'
```

Check what files are monitored by running

```
DEBUG=nodemon:watch nodemon server.js -i "**/old/**" -i "**/img/**"
```

-i is an alternative to --ignore. Check out the available parameters with nodemon --help

Answer (score 5):

If like me nothing is working for you, follow my instructions.

Do not use the '' around your path('login.json' is wrong for example)

And CTRL + S won't suffice, you need to close the terminal and use the command `npm run devStart` AGAIN if you want your changes to take place in your packages.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js --ignore login.json"
  },
```