# Starting Loopback with nodemon

Tags: strongloop, nodemon

I would like to restart automatically my local strongloop/loopback app when js & json are modified. I am testing with nodemon but the app is always restarting even if js or json are not modified.

Is there an alternative for solving this problem ?

Thanks, 
Christophe

Comment: Show the nodemon command you are using. When I use: 'nodemon server/server.js', it works fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

if you would like to run the project with nodemon just add `dev` command under the `script` json object and add additional `config json` inside of the `package.json` file.

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "dev" : "nodemon src/index.ts",
  ...
},
"nodemonConfig": {
  "verbose": true,
  "watch": [ "src/" ],
  "ignore": [ "dist/*" ],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "npm start"
},
```

and then run the project with command `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in few steps:

1. install nodemon: `npm i --save-dev nodemon`
2. open **package.json** in section **scripts** add new line: `"dev" : "nodemon server/server.js --watch common --watch server"`
3. run your server with command: `npm run dev`

Each time when You change something in folders: **common** or **server** **nodemon** will restart application with provided changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another file that is constantly changing that nodemon is monitoring.  If so, you can use the --ignore command.
For example
[Nodemon - exclusion of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120004/nodemon-exclusion-of-files][1])