# Nodemon - ignore whole dir but except one file

Tags: javascript, nodemon

This is my `nodemon.json` file:

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "ignore": ["app/public/"]
}
```

what should I add to not ignore `"app/public/compiled/components.js"` file but still ignore all others files in `app/public/` dir (and sub dirs)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120153/2845389 this may help

Comment: I read that (and official doc too) but there are only simple examples there. Maybe it's not even possible with this file pattern that is used in nodemon (because it's not regular expression, as far as I tested).