# Nodemon: Ignore filename in any subdirectory inside src

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I was searching for how to add to the ignore list a filename located at any subdirectory inside `src`.
I had not so much lucky in my search...

I'm using a `nodemon.json` file

```
{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts,js,json",
    "ignore": [
        "src/database",
        "src/providers/core/jobs",
        "src/config/sequelize/sequelize-cli.conf.js",
        "src/**/*/tmpl.*" # this line doesn't work
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120004/nodemon-exclusion-of-files

Comment: I need an abstraction of the possibles paths

Comment: Updated at main post

Answer (score 0):

I needed to omit all those files:

```
# APP
src/app/controllers/tmpl.ts
src/app/helpers/tmpl.ts
src/app/models/tmpl.ts
src/app/routes/tmpl.routes.ts

# DATABASE
src/database/generators/tmpl.js
src/database/migrations/tmpl
src/database/seeders/tmpl

# MIDDLEWARES
src/middlewares/tmpl.ts
```

The most close I got was with this rules:

```
ignore: [
    "src/*/tmpl.ts",
    "src/app/*/tmpl.ts",
    "src/database/*/tmpl.js"
]
```