# Nodemon restars on JSON save

Tags: javascript, nodemon

So I was making a chat like program in js, and I was using nodemon to run It. I have that the chat autosaves into the JSON. However when It does that the whole nodemon server restars, creating a problem. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120004/nodemon-exclusion-of-files helps?

Answer (score 0):

[Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) allows you to set a configuration in `nodemon.json` (root of your project directory), or you can call it with `nodemon index.js --config mynodemonconfig.json`

add your folder of json to your ignore  or remove "json" from ext (not recommended)

```
{
    "ext": "ejs js styl pug json", 
    "ignore": [
        ".git",
        "node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wait where do i find the nodemon.json. I have a package.json but the code you mentioned up here isn't featured there

Comment: you have to create `nodemon.json`

Comment: Ok, do I have to create o put it in a specific folder?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js --ignore login.json"
  },

This worked thanks still

Comment: normally you'd put it where you are calling `nodemon` and it would automatically pick it up, alternatively you can specify the path using `--config /myfolder/myconfig.json`